# trying to receive JSON as a JObject

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am trying to bring in JSON data into my method. I am using Postman to send my data.

An example of my JSON is...
{"FieldData" : {"name": "david"}, "Project" : 20, "Version" : 1}

My model is

```
public class IncomingFormData
{
    public JObject FieldData { get; set; }
    public int Project { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

My method is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveFormData(IncomingFormData FieldData)
    {
         string myField = FieldData.FieldData.ToString();
    }
```

I am getting null in FieldData.FieldData and the Project and Version are showing 0.

In my earlier version that worked, I had...

An example of my JSON is...

{FieldData : '{"name": "david"}', "Project" : 20, "Version" : 1}

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveFormData(string FieldData, int Project, int Version)
    {
         string myField = FieldData;
    }
```

Unfortunately for me, in this version, if the value of one of the FieldData objects has an apostrophe in it, it fails. (This is correct according to the RFC).

So, I had to rewrite it.

Now, I can't get anything coming in from Postman. The method is called but nothing coming in.

Postman has Accept application/json and content-type application/json set.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really the way I wanted to do this, but hey, it works.

My original method was in a regular MVC controller. When I tried to send the JSON, I was getting the error **Cannot create abstract class**

However, creating an api controller instead, with pretty much the same signature **JObject FieldData** and from there, passing into my regular controller, it just works.

The code below is in the api controller.

```
    public JsonResult Post([FromBody]JObject FieldData)
    {
        //string myData = FieldData.ToString();

        FormsController form = new FormsController();

        return form.SaveFormData(FieldData);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try pass this: {"IncomingFormData":{"FieldData" : {"name": "david"}, "Project" : 20, "Version" : 1}}

Comment: No, this didn't work. I still have null for FieldData and 0 for Project and Version.
The FieldData, Project and Version is already a wrap for the {"name":"david"} json. That json is dynamic in nature, so I can't know what will be in it.